# Stepper motor, need forward, reverse and to hold weight

Tags: pi-3b+

I am working on a project in which i would like to lift and hold open a small wooden door at a certain time of day and then lower it again. Right now I would be happy if I could just lower it. I can lift it just fine with this code as well as hold the weight`enter code here`, but can't figure out how to lower it.

When running the script, it prompts you to enter a number. entering 50 will have one revolution on the stepper motor, 25 will be half, etc. It would be great if I could enter -50, -400, etc to lower the door.

If I change lift_halfstep to lower_halfstep, the motor does change direction, so it's not a wiring issue...just a lack of coding knowledge issue.

Here is the code with the help of a youtube video:

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

timer = 0
pins = [12,11,13,15]
for p in pins:
    GPIO.setup(p, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(p, 0)

# Raising up the weight
lift_halfstep = [
    [1,0,0,0],
    [1,0,1,0],
    [0,0,1,0],
    [0,1,1,0],
    [0,1,0,0],
    [0,1,0,1],
    [0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,1],
]

# Lowering the weight
lower_halfstep = [
    [1,0,0,1],
    [0,0,0,1],
    [0,1,0,1],
    [0,1,0,0],
    [0,1,1,0],
    [0,0,1,0],
    [1,0,1,0],
    [1,0,0,0],
]

# For output number, 50 is one revolution
while(1):
    n=int(input("input number: "))
    for number in range(n):
        for s in range(8):
            for p in range(4):
                GPIO.output(pins[p], lift_halfstep[s][p])
            sleep(0.01)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: what stepper controller are you using? there is usually a dir and a step pin.  setting the dir appropriately and cycling step high low multiple times should move it in the direction set by the dir pin some rotation proportional to the number of cycles on the step pin, as long as you have sufficient power to rotate the motor by an increment for each step pin cycle.

Comment: L298N.  If i change the entry lift_halfstep to lower_halfstep, the motor will turn the other direction...the code just doesn't have it.  I'm not sure of the code to add or modify to allow running both directions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just needed python code to switch lift to lower if a negative is provided (key piece is in `if n < 0:`) while leaving most of it alone:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

pins = [12,11,13,15]
for p in pins:
    GPIO.setup(p, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(p, 0)

lift_halfstep = [ [1,0,0,0], [1,0,1,0], [0,0,1,0], [0,1,1,0], [0,1,0,0], [0,1,0,1], [0,0,0,1], [1,0,0,1], ]

lower_halfstep = [ [1,0,0,1], [0,0,0,1], [0,1,0,1], [0,1,0,0], [0,1,1,0], [0,0,1,0], [1,0,1,0], [1,0,0,0], ]

#for output number, 50 is one revolution
while(1):
    n=int(input("input number: "))
    if n < 0:
        n= n*-1
        steplist = lower_halfstep
    else:
        steplist = lift_halfstep
    for number in range(n):
        for s in range(8):
            for p in range(4):
                GPIO.output(pins[p], steplist[s][p])
                sleep(0.01)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: That's the answer!  It lifts and lowers just like i need it.  it will hold the weight at the top.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.